# Parent-Child Dataset - Nested Relation: Does not insert new child row

Tags: c#, dataset

what I have is a DataSet with 1 parent and 1 child table. Relation is nested. Update cascading.
Problem is when I add a new child row in UI, the child row is not inserted.

I update like so:

```
parentTableAdapter.Update(dataSet);
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just being stupid.

I needed to update the child rows seperatly like so:

childTableAdapter.Update(dataSet);

I tried that but due to my fiddling, the "Update" command from the TableAdapter was somehow missing. So I thought, I only need to Update the parent.
I re-added it by selecting "New" as UPDATE, SELECT, DELETE in DataSetDesigner and then just startet the Config-Wizard to fill in the commands.